# Rails 4 upgrade and settings.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 3 app where I am using the following convention for setting default values...

Default settings live in `config/settings.yml`and look like...

```
twitter_app_secret: '234wer234'
facebook_app_id: 'notset'
facebook_app_secret: 'notset'
session_token: '123456789er3se901234567890'
```

...and any wher in the app I can call these settings like Settings.twitter_app_secret. In in the console its like...

```
ruby-2.1.5@learn marklocklear:learn marklocklear$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.21)
2.1.5 :001 > Settings.twitter_app_secret
 => "234wer234"
```

I am working on updating this app to Rails 4 and the app will not load with the following error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant Settings`

This is a legacy app that I have inherited. Did some of the Rails Magic of Rails 3 change in Rails 4 to cause this not to work?

Comment: Settings is not a class that you have created before hand. You will need to create it, or better yet, use `Rails.application.secrets.xyz` in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: do you maybe have a Settings module/class in lib/ that's no longer autoloaded since the upgrade?

Comment: Thanks. It just clicked for me that Settings must be a class, however I don't see that class setup anywhere in the original app. There is a settings_helper.rb in app/helpers, but it just has the module name SettingsHelper with nothing configured.

Comment: Also, if I enter `Settings.class` in the console I get `=> RailsConfig::Options`

Comment: I don't know who voted down this question, but it actually helped me today when doing some legacy migration. So I voted one up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the legacy app was using https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_config/versions/0.99.0 gem. This is a legacy gem (Rails 3). The updated gem is https://github.com/railsconfig/config. I installed this gem in the Rails 4 version and was able to keep all my current settings in place.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in Hunter's comment, settings isn't a pre-configured class. There are several ways you could go about fixing your problem with minimal reconfiguration:

First, you could do add the configurations listed to config/application.rb like this:

```
config.twitter_app_secret: '234wer234'
config.facebook_app_id: 'notset'
config.facebook_app_secret: 'notset'
config.session_token: '123456789er3se901234567890'
```

and then access them in your application like this:

```
Rails.configuration.twitter_app_secret
```

Second, you could just add the values to config.yml instead of settings.yml. A detailed explanation of the process can be found at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

I'm guessing you have a class in your app called Setting, which pulls the values from that YAML file. That's the only way I could see your console output working, unless there's some special configuration in place.

Answer (score -3):

You should be using environment variables.

`ENV['twitter_app_secret']`

If you would like to include them in a file, consider using the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) in development.

Comment: How does this answer the original question?